# Run code when group of ajax requests finish

Tags: javascript, ajax

I made a basic method that handles ajax, but I am not sure how to watch for when a group of requests (not necessarily all the ajax requests on the page) are complete so I can run additional code.

Here is the method:

```
request: function(options, success){
    var xmlhttp;
    var url = typeof options === "string" ? options : options.url;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            success(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    };
    var base = document.querySelector("base") || {href: "/"};
    xmlhttp.open("GET", base.href + ("/" + url).replace("//", "/"));
    xmlhttp.send();
    return this;
}
```

I am thinking I would like something like this to watch:

```
var requests = [];

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    requests.push(obj.request(url[i]));
}

// This one doesn't matter:
obj.request("/some/other/request.json");

// complete() is what would handle the items
requests.complete(function(data){
    // Run code when all requests finish
});
```

Is something like the possible and how? I would like to keep away from 3rd party libraries if possible.

I think my method needs to return a `Promise` instead but I am not sure...

Comment: in the complete function what will data be, a concatanation of all the responses?, or are you specifying a function that will be called once for each response

Comment: data would be an array of all the result responses.

Comment: yes so you would push the responses to an array, and pass to the complete callback when the count of outstanding requests is 0, see my explanation below, you can have a simple object that will maintain the requests/responses array and count

Comment: have you checked out my solution below, its tested and works a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your `obj` track all AJAX requests it receives, and let it track how many requests are complete.

You can do something really simple with

```
count: 0,
responses : [],
request: function(options, success){
    this.count++;
    ... etc etc
```

So `count` stores the number of active requests, and then

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
        this.count--;
        this.responses.push(xmlhttp.responseText);
        if (this.count == 0)
            // execute all responses
    }
};
```

Comment: Downvote? Let me know if I'm not clear enough with my answer.

Answer (score -1):

If your aim is to have multiple requests that are made and handled by a response callback, and then once all requests are complete call a complete call back function.

Then, you need to have a list of request objects each with a handler, and then a request manager that will take the requests execute them and maintain a count of outstanding requests and and check if the count is zero after each response and call the complete callback if remaining is 0.

```
function RequestManager(complete)
{
    this.count = 0;
    this.responses = [];
    this.complete = complete;
}

RequestManager.prototype.addRequest = function(options, base)
{
    this.count++;
    var thisObj = this;
    var xmlhttp;
    var url = typeof options === "string" ? options : options.url;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else{// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(xmlhttp.readyState === 4 && xmlhttp.status === 200){
            thisObj.responses.push(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        thisObj.count--;
                        if(thisObj.count == 0)
                        thisObj.complete(thisObj.responses);
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET", base.href + ("/" + url).replace("//", "/"));
    xmlhttp.send();
}

var requestManager = new RequestManager(function(responses){
    console.log(responses);
});

var url = ['test2.html', 'test2.html', 'test2.html'];

for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    requestManager.addRequest(url[i], { href: 'http://localhost' });
}
```

Comment: downvoted, why?, complete and reuseable component, no 3rd party dependency and cross browser